# what is the best way to dynamically show/hide elements base on filtering an array in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to show/hide some elements base on a multiple select in vuejs, currently, I am using methods, I am curious to know is there a better way to do that? like computed properties? and how to do that?

the code sandbox example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-filter-bp72r?file=/src/pages/Index.vue

```
<q-select
      filled
      outlined
      dense
      multiple
      options-dense
      v-model="groupBy.fields"
      :options="reporterlocationGroupByFileldOptions"
      label="fields"
      emit-value
      map-options
      option-value="value"
      option-label="name"
      color="orange"
    />

<!-- elements to show/hide -->
    <q-select
      v-if="visibleFilter('province')"
      filled
      outlined
      dense
      options-dense
      v-model="filtering.provinceId"
      :options="provinceOptions"
      label="province"
      emit-value
      map-options
      option-value="id"
      option-label="name"
      class="q-my-sm"
      color="red"
    />
    <q-select
      v-if="visibleFilter('city')"
      filled
      outlined
      dense
      options-dense
      v-model="filtering.cityId"
      :options="cityOptions"
      label="city"
      emit-value
      map-options
      option-value="id"
      option-label="name"
      class="q-my-sm"
      color="green"
    />
```

my current solution with methods:

```
data() {
  return {
    filtering: {
      provinceId: '',
      cityId: ''
    },
    reporterlocationGroupByFileldOptions: [
      { name: 'province', orderByDesc: 'province', value: 'province' },
      { name: 'city', orderByDesc: 'city', value: 'city' }
    ]
  }
},
methods: {
    visibleFilter(filterName) {
      var field = this.groupBy.fields.find(x => x === filterName)
      if (field) return true
      return false
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please add some relevant code in the question to create a [mcve]. Just enough to understand the problem by looking at the code. If the external link is deleted or inaccessible, this question will have no future value

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly v-for over your field property in the groupBy property and move your options and v-model under the same object:

```
  filtering: {
    provinceId: {
     value: '',
     option: yourOptions
    },
    cityId: {
     value: '',
     option: yourOptions
    },
    sectionId: {
     value: '',
     option: yourOptions
    },
  },

   <div class="col-xs-12 q-mb-sx" v-for="field in groupBy.fields">
    <q-select
      :key="field"
      filled
      outlined
      dense
      options-dense
      v-model="filtering[field].value"
      :options="filtering[field].option"
      label="green"
      emit-value
      map-options
      option-value="id"
      option-label="name"
      class="q-my-sm"
      color="green"
    />
  </div>
```

PS you have a typo in your code, "fileds" instead of "fields"

Comment: thank you for your idea, but they are not going to have the same v-model and :options, I updated my code sandbox example with different v-model and options, and thank you for pointing "fileds"

Comment: You can still make it. v-model =  v-model="filtering[field]" - using the v-for="field in fields"

Comment: thank you, that is a good idea, but it is not a general solution, because maybe I need to show/hide different element types in different places.

Comment: I would argue this is the best solution. Because you can v-if out your component with the same logic, putting a "show" property somewhere in the fields.

Comment: yes, it`s the best solution for my example, but imagine I have 3 different sections, one section (A) is at the right side of the page and others (B, C) are at the left, and I have 10 elements to show/hide, each one has its specific section (A or B or C) to put into.